# Refused to apply style because its MIME type (application/json) is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. Filament

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-filament

I am getting error: Refused to apply style from 'https://api.pickmode.pl/filament/assets/app.css?id=4c051b8ff61afd3b5499c7dff41d944d' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I am using apache web server with laravel app and filament admin panel. On my localhost with 'php artisan serve' everything is working.

my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
  

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"

    AddType text/css .css

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.css(\?.*)?$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [T=text/css]
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.ico|\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.eot|\.svg|\.ttf|\.woff|\.woff2|\.otf|\.pdf)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# If this https://api.pickmode.pl/filament/assets/app.css is requested, then header will be added to response
# Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
# Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
# Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"

</IfModule>
```

I tried to force add text/css header in .htaccess file but it did not helped.

Comment: Have you overwritten or extended the AssetController? Looking at [their GitHub](https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/blob/6ef146f19c1a456c8378437be765bd77cf5e490f/packages/admin/src/Http/Controllers/AssetController.php#L58), that controller is what manages the filetype for anything in the assets folder.

Comment: Nope, i did not. I tried to overwrite manifest and get rid of get parameter of index.css in vendor directory. It helped but I think that it is not right solution.